# AWS EC2 SSH Via Role and Accessing S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have created an instance that I can access via the CLI on Terminal.

If you have no roles you have to do `'aws configure'` which then you put in your users access keys.

If you attach a role to full access you can do anything you want via the command line.

Therefore, if I have created a user and I am doing an `SSH ec2-user@ip` how does the role come into play? Does it mean since I have gave it a role it takes some credentials or are you supposed to sign in `[username]@[ip]` to restrict a user?

Or,
Does it mean assigning a role to the EC2 the user who is doing an SSH or is grabbing data is only limited by whatever the Role says?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any user that gains access to the EC2 instance will get the role/credentials that are associated with the attached instance profile.

AWS does not restrict the credentials to certain user(s). You can add an iptable rule to restrict users connecting to the metadata server `169.254.169.254` that supplies the instance profile.